# address book using json html javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

[image: address book using json html javascript]

I am working on Address book using HTML,CSS and Javascript. First I am reading some data entries from a JSON file. Then storing those entries into local storage. Then I am taking input from the user in few input fields through the function called **addToBook()**. And then storing all the data in JSON format in the variable called **addressBook**. But when i am trying to print this data in the function called **showaddressBook()**. It is not happening as it is showing as Undefined in the chrome console. Refer to this line(*console.log(addressBook[i].practice_name*);) in the function **showaddressBook()**. Any idea guys. Thanks in advance.

```
window.onload = function(){
var quickAddFormDiv = document.querySelector('.quickaddForm');  
var AddBtn = document.getElementById('Add');
// Form Fields
var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
var firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var specialty = document.getElementById('specialty');
var practicename = document.getElementById('practicename');
// Divs etc.
var addBookDiv = document.querySelector('.addbook');

var addressBook = [];
var people;
localStorage.clear();
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
//To display the contents of JSON file
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
               people = response.people;
               //var output = "";
               var str1 = '';
                for(var i = 0; i <people.length;i++){
                    str1 += '<div id="entry">';                 
                    str1 += '<div id="name"><p>' + people[i].last_name +', '+people[i].first_name+ '</p></div>';
                    str1 += '<div id="email"><p>' + people[i].email_address + '</p></div>';
                    str1 += '<div id="practicename"><p>' + people[i].practice_name + '</p></div>';                  
                    str1 += '<div id="specialty"><p>' + people[i].specialty + '</p></div>';
                    str1 += '<div id="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + i + '">Delete</a></div>';
                    }
                for(var i = 0; i < people.length;i++){
                    var obj = new jsonStructure(people[i].last_name,people[i].first_name,people[i].email_address,people[i].specialty,people[i].practice_name);                  
                    addressBook.push(obj);                      
                    localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(addressBook);
                }

                document.getElementsByClassName("addbook")[0].innerHTML = str1;

            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "people.json", true);
        xhttp.send();
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        AddBtn.addEventListener("click", addToBook);
        //var addressBook = [];
        addBookDiv.addEventListener("click", removeEntry);

        function jsonStructure(lastname,firstname,email,specialty,practicename){
            this.lastname = lastname;
            this.lastname += ", "+firstname;                
            this.email = email;
            this.specialty = specialty;
            this.practicename = practicename;
        }
        function addToBook(){
            var isNull = lastname.value!='' && firstname.value!='' && email.value!='' && specialty.value!='' && practicename.value!='';
            if(isNull){
                // format the input into a valid JSON structure
                var obj = new jsonStructure(lastname.value,firstname.value,email.value,specialty.value,practicename.value);                 
                addressBook.push(obj);
                localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(addressBook);
                console.log(localStorage['addbook']);
                clearForm();
                showaddressBook();
            }
        }
        function removeEntry(e){
        // Remove an entry from the addressBook

            if(e.target.classList.contains('delbutton')){
                var remID = e.target.getAttribute('data-id');                   
                addressBook.splice(remID,1);
                localStorage['addbook'] = JSON.stringify(addressBook);
                showaddressBook();
            }
        }
        function clearForm(){
            var formFields = document.querySelectorAll('.formFields');
            for(var i in formFields){
                formFields[i].value = '';
            }
        }
        function showaddressBook(){
            if(localStorage['addbook'] === undefined){
                localStorage['addbook'] = '';
            } else {
                addressBook = JSON.parse(localStorage['addbook']);
                addBookDiv.innerHTML = '';
                var str = '';
                for(var i = 0; i <addressBook.length;i++){

                    str += '<div id="entry">';                  
                    str += '<div id="name"><p>' + addressBook[i].last_name +', '+addressBook[i].first_name+ '</p></div>';
                    str += '<div id="email"><p>' + addressBook[i].email_address + '</p></div>';
                    str += '<div id="practicename"><p>' + addressBook[i].practice_name + '</p></div>';                  
                    str += '<div id="specialty"><p>' + addressBook[i].specialty + '</p></div>';
                    str += '<div id="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + i + '">Delete</a></div>';
                    console.log(addressBook[i].practice_name);
                }

            }
        }

        showaddressBook();
}
```

Comment: what is the result if you print `console.log(addressBook[i])` ?

Comment: its weird, when I print "console.log(addressBook[i])", I get the JSON objects. But when I print "console.log(addressBook[i].practice_name);", I get Undefiend on console.

Comment: just add that object output in your question, so that i can catch

Comment: https://ibb.co/gr8n8F, https://ibb.co/kiTb2a.   Please refer to these images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **typo** mistakes,

- `practice_name` should be `practicename`
- `last_name` should be `lastname`
- `first_name` should be `firstname`
- `email_address` should be `email`

**Try:**

```
for(var i = 0; i <addressBook.length;i++){
    str += '<div id="entry">';                  
    str += '<div id="name"><p>' + addressBook[i].lastname +', '+addressBook[i].firstname+ '</p></div>';
    str += '<div id="email"><p>' + addressBook[i].email + '</p></div>';
    str += '<div id="practicename"><p>' + addressBook[i].practicename + '</p></div>';                  
    str += '<div id="specialty"><p>' + addressBook[i].specialty + '</p></div>';
    str += '<div id="del"><a href="#" class="delbutton" data-id="' + i + '">Delete</a></div>';
    console.log(addressBook[i].practicename);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry. Thats true but when i am trying to print "console.log(addressBook[i].last_name);". still I am getting Undefined.

Comment: Dude, your `last_name` should also be `lastname`, check the console.log data for each key :)

Comment: My bad.. I got confused with the key names. Thank you so much.

Comment: I need your little help. Can you tell me how to sort this data after displaying it ? I am new to web development and I have this project to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) for client side sorting, you need to change your html structure to `table` structure for that

Comment: @PRIYAMSHARMA Also variable names in JavaScript are generally in camelCase - being consistent will not only help avoid these errors but also help other people work with your code!  See https://github.com/rwaldron/idiomatic.js/ or https://github.com/airbnb/javascript